# R - Fill in missing values, with the previous value in the column, times another column, and iterate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a time series where I need to calculate a counterfactual value based based on a column of historical growth rates. The `counterfactual` column is the exact same as the the `observed_value` column up until March of 2020, where the values need to be recomputed using historical growth rates from the `growth_rate` column. The idea is to fill in all the missing values after Feb 2020, by multiplying the value of the previous month with the historical growth rate. Here is the data

```
df <- data.frame("month" = c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April"),
                 "year" = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020),
                 "observed_value" = c(15,18,22,19),
                 "growth_rate" = c(0.001, -0.549, 0.4788, -0.11),
                 "counterfactual" = c(15,18,NA,NA))
```

So in this example, we fill in the counterfactual value for March 2020 by multiplying the Feb 2020 value * (1+growth rate) in the row we are filling in. In this example, the calculation for the missing value for March 2020 = 18*(1+0.4788) = 26.62. And now we iterate and using the counterfactual March 2020 value we computed to calculate the counterfactual for April 2020. For example April 2020 = 26.62 * 0.89....and so on until we have a full counterfactual column. Note, all values after Feb 2020 in the counterfactual column are NA.

```
desired_output <- data.frame("month" = c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April"),
                          "year" = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020),
                          "observed_value" = c(15,18,22,19),
                          "growth_rate" = c(0.001, -0.549, 0.4788, -0.11),
                          "counterfactual" = c(15,18,26.62,23.69))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you observe, all values after a date are NA, you can do this:

```r
miss <- which(is.na(df$counterfactual))

df$counterfactual[miss] <- 
  tail(df$observed_value[-miss], 1) * 
  cumprod(1 + df$growth_rate[miss])

df
#>   month year observed_value growth_rate counterfactual
#> 1   Jan 2020             15      0.0010       15.00000
#> 2   Feb 2020             18     -0.5490       18.00000
#> 3 March 2020             22      0.4788       26.61840
#> 4 April 2020             19     -0.1100       23.69038
```

If not all NA's are contiguous, this solution does not apply and you must iterate or group by NA's groups.

Comment: just curious, would you know how to do this using the tidyverse packages (dplyr, purr) without referencing any global values (for example the `miss` value in the example). In other words, everything in one pipe. Thanks

Comment: I think we do not take advantage of dplyr here. You can do someting like `df %>% mutate(counterfactual = coalesce(counterfactual, last(observed_value[!is.na(counterfactual)]) * cumprod(1 + if_else(is.na(counterfactual), growth_rate, 0))))`